# Despite adding a unique key, react is throwing a warning

Tags: reactjs

Despite adding a unique key to a element **key={item.?key}** I'm still getting the following warning:

**Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.**
**Check the top-level render call using `<ol>`.**

```
import React from 'react';

function myComponent(...data) {
  return (
    <section className="my-component">
      <ol className="my-component__cards">
        {data[0].items.map((item) => (
          <a key={item?.key} className="my-component__slide">
            <li>
              <h3>{item?.title?.rendered}</h3>
              <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: item?.content?.rendered }} />
            </li>
          </a>
        ))}
      </ol>
    </section>
  );
}

export default myComponent;
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you show `data[0].items`

Comment: shouldn't it be `item?.key` ? you have `.?` but optional chaining is `?.`

Comment: Sorry It was a typo in my question. I corrected it. It is item?.key. It doesn't matter which property in the object I'm adding as a key to the a tag, I'm always getting the same warning.

Comment: Don't use optional chaining for key, you must provide an unique key

Answer (score 1):

if your `item` has a unique prop named as `key`, this could must do fine and you need to replace `?` with `!`. (typescript problems, typescript solving methods :D )
but if you're not sure about it, just use `index` as the key prop.

```js
{data[0].items.map((item, index) => (
  <a key={index} ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw you just render array. So you can set `key` as index of item.

```
{data[0].items.map((item, index) => (
  <a key={index} ...
```